# Lost connection to MySQL server during query exception

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am getting the below error while executing the prepared statement

> (2013) Lost connection to MySQL server during queryexception
>
> I have checked almost all the questions posted on this topic before posting but could not find the answer. so please do not close.

I am new to PHP and MYSQL so please correct if I have made any mistake

MY Code:-

```
<?php
class sanitize_insert{
protected $prepared_stmt;
protected $db_sqli;
public function prepare_sanitized_insert($created_by)
{
    if(!is_integer($created_by))
    {
        throw new InvalidArgException("Invalid argument(s) type. Expected integer(s)"); //to be defined
    }
    
    
    
    $query = "insert into requests_v(user_id,property_id,request_type,description,to_user_id,created_on,last_update_date,created_by,last_updated_by) values (?,?,?,?,?,now(),now(),8,8);";
            if(!is_resource($this->db_sqli))
    {
        $this->db_sqli = mysqli_connect('host','user','password','dbname');
    }
    if(!$this->prepared_stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query))
    {
        return false;   
    }
    $this->prepared_stmt->bind_param('iiisi', $user_id, $property_id, $req_type, $desc,$to_id);
    //$result = $this->db_sqli->execute($this->prepared_stmt);
    return true;
}

public function execute_insert()
{
    if(!is_object($this->prepared_stmt))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(!is_resource($this->db_sqli))
    {
        $this->db_sqli = mysqli_connect('host','user','password','dbname');
    }
    $result = $this->prepared_stmt->execute();
    return $result;
}


}
```

When I execute the prepared statement inside the method 'prepare_sanitized_insert', it gets executed without any error but when I execute it inside the method "execute_insert" it fails with the error :-

> (2013) Lost connection to MySQL server during query
>
> var_dump of the prepared statement just before the execution
>
> object(mysqli_stmt)#4 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(5) ["field_count"]=> int(0) **["errno"]=> int(2013) ["error"]=> string(44) "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" ["error_list"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["errno"]=> int(2013) ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "HY000" ["error"]=> string(44) "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" } } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "HY000" ["id"]=> int(1)** }

Could someone please help?

Comment: Did you execute `prepare_sanitized_insert()` before `execute_insert()`?

Comment: Yes I executed prepare_sanitized_insert() before execute_insert().

Comment: Why are you using `mysqli_connect` to assign db_sqli in `prepare_sanitized_insert()`, and `db_factory::get_db_sqli()` in `execute_insert()`? Can you log/echo in that if statement to see if it's trying to reassign the variable?

Comment: Why do you have a mysqli_connect() call inside the prepare function, yet use `get_db_sqli()` in the execute call? Seems like you're using multiple DIFFERENT methods of connecting to the db. I doubt that a statement prepared on one mysql connection is usable via another separate connection.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion!!! Earlier I was using a factory class to get the my_sqli object. I have edited the code please have a look. Also i am updating the var_dump of the prepared statement.

Comment: @SaurabhJain There is an entire page of the Mysql manual devoted to this subject. Check it out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Comment: honestly, you should just pass a mysqli_connection resource to this class in the constructor and not have to fool around with connection logic in this class (i.e. dependency injection).  Just fail instantiation of connection isn't passed.

Comment: `$query` variable has additional `;` !

Comment: @SaberHajRabiee one ';' is part of query string.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I got rid of the error by removing my_sqli initialization in "execute_insert" method. I'll try to figure out why  $this->db_sqli is not a resource. Your thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mixed up object-oriented style and procedural style .

object-oriented style
Note the **new**

```
$this->db_sqli = new mysqli('host','user','password','dbname');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
}

$query = "insert into requests_v(user_id, ...) values (?,?,?,?,?,now(), ...)";
```

wrong

```
if(!$this->prepared_stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query)) {
```

correct

```
if ($this->prepared_stmt = $this->db_sqli->prepare($query)) {

    $this->prepared_stmt->bind_param('iiisi', $user_id, $property_id, ..., ...);
```

---

Prozedural style (The procedural style was used in the question)
Note **without new**

```
$this->db_sqli = mysqli_connect('host','user','password','dbname');
...
$query = "insert into requests_v(user_id, ...) values (?,?,?,?,?,now(), ...)";
```

wrong

```
if (!$this->prepared_stmt = $this->db_sqli->prepare($query)) {
```

correct

```
if (!$this->prepared_stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->db_sqli, $query)) {
```

wrong

```
$this->prepared_stmt->bind_param('iiisi', $user_id, $property_id, ...,...);
```

correct

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($this->prepared_stmt,'iiisi',$user_id, ..., ...,...);
```

wrong

```
$result = $this->prepared_stmt->execute();
```

correct

```
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($this->prepared_stmt);
```

---

You have to decide for one of the two `object-oriented style` or `procedural style` .

---

you could use a constructor (also mentioned @Saber Haj Rabiee)
object-oriented style

```
 class sanitize_insert{

   protected $prepared_stmt;
   protected $db_sqli;
   public    $OK = TRUE;

  public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db)
  { 
    $this->db_sqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db); 
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
      $this->OK = FALSE;
    }
  }
```

call it like

```
 $sanitizeclass = new sanitize_insert($host, $user, $pass, $db);
 if ($sanitizeclass->OK) {
  ....
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the help. Initially i was using oo approach only but then I encountered this error, I shifted database connectivity code to this file and mixed both the styles while trying out possibilities to get rid of the error.